# Slickgrid, how to copy-paste cells to excel?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, excel, copy-paste, slickgrid

Question:

I'm using jqGrid to display a table.
However, performance in Internet Explorer 9 & 8 isn't good if it has to display more than 20 rows...

I've tried SlickGrid, and its performance in Internet Explorer seems to be much better for my case.

My only problem that prevents me from switching to SlickGrid right-now is, that with SlickGrid, you cannot just copy-paste a range of cells FROM SlickGrid TO excel PROPERLY.

Copy-pasting transposes the cells, so that the columns are the rows, and the rows the columns (ok I know you can transpose back in excel, but I'm not the average end-user. And besides, having to do that is annoying) ...

With jqGrid, this works flawlessly.
Note that I expressly don't want to output the data as CSV/XLS/XLSX file.

Anybody knows how I can make SlickGrid copy-paste cells to Excel correctly (non-transposed) ?

Comment: Seems like a bug with Slickgrid more than anything ...?  Might be best to record in the issues list: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues

Comment: Oops, I see this is already an open issue:  https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/pull/359

Answer (score 2):

See this plugin:
http://labs.nereo.fr/slick.html

But it has 3 issues, 
A.can't paste to excel properly,
B. will destroy an extra cell when pasting to SlickGrid
C. there are errors when the source range is bigger than the destination

I made some changes to address them. 
See below:

```
(function ($) {
  // register namespace
  $.extend(true, window, {
    "Slick": {
      "CellExternalCopyManager": CellExternalCopyManager
    }
  });


  function CellExternalCopyManager(options) {
    /*
      This manager enables users to copy/paste data from/to an external Spreadsheet application
      such as MS-Excel® or OpenOffice-Spreadsheet.

      Since it is not possible to access directly the clipboard in javascript, the plugin uses
      a trick to do it's job. After detecting the keystroke, we dynamically create a textarea
      where the browser copies/pastes the serialized data. 

      options:
        copiedCellStyle : sets the css className used for copied cells. default : "copy-manager"
        dataItemColumnValueExtractor : option to specify a custom column value extractor function

    */
    var _grid;
    var _self = this;
    var _copiedRanges;
    var _options = options || {};
    var _copiedCellStyle = _options.copiedCellStyle || "copy-manager";


    var keyCodes = {
      'C':67,
      'V':86
    }

    function init(grid) {
      _grid = grid;
      _grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(handleKeyDown);      
    }

    function destroy() {
      _grid.onKeyDown.unsubscribe(handleKeyDown);
    }

    function getDataItemValueForColumn(item, columnDef) {
      if (_options.dataItemColumnValueExtractor) {
        return _options.dataItemColumnValueExtractor(item, columnDef);
      }
      return item[columnDef.field];
    }

    function setDataItemValueForColumn(item, columnDef, value) {
      if (_options.dataItemColumnValueSetter) {
        return _options.dataItemColumnValueSetter(item, columnDef, value);
      }
      return item[columnDef.field] = value;
    }


    function _createTextBox(innerText){
      var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
      ta.style.position = 'absolute';
      ta.style.left = '-1000px';
      ta.style.top = '-1000px';
      ta.value = innerText;
      document.body.appendChild(ta);
      document.designMode = 'off';
      ta.focus();

      return ta;
    }
    function _decodeTabularData(_grid, ta){
      var columns = _grid.getColumns();
      var clipText = ta.value;
      var clipRows = clipText.split("\r\n"); 
     var clippeds = [];

      document.body.removeChild(ta);

      for (var i=0; i<clipRows.length; i++) {
        if (clipRows[i]!="") // get rid of the last ""
          clippeds[i] = clipRows[i].split(String.fromCharCode(9)); //  "\t" 
      }

      var selectedCell = _grid.getActiveCell();
      var activeRow = selectedCell.row + pageSize*pageNum;// getActiveCell.row starts from 0  for each page.
      var activeCell = selectedCell.cell;
      var desty = activeRow;
      var destx = activeCell;

      var data = _grid.getData().getItems();  

      for (var y = 0; y < clippeds.length; y++){
        for (var x = 0; x < clippeds[y].length; x++){
            var desty = activeRow + y;
          var destx = activeCell + x;
            if (desty < data.length && destx < grid.getColumns().length ) { 
                data[desty][columns[destx].field] = clippeds[y][x];
            if ( data[desty].hasOwnProperty('id')) 
              changedIds.push(data[desty].id);// record changed id used by saving function
          }
        }
      }

      _grid.invalidate();
    }


    function handleKeyDown(e, args) {
      var ranges;
      if (!_grid.getEditorLock().isActive()) {

        //ESC
        if (e.which == $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
          if (_copiedRanges) {
            e.preventDefault();
            clearCopySelection();
            _self.onCopyCancelled.notify({ranges: _copiedRanges});
            _copiedRanges = null;
          }
        }

        if (e.which == keyCodes.C && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) {    // CTRL + C
          ranges = _grid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedRanges();

          if (ranges.length != 0) {
            _copiedRanges = ranges;
            markCopySelection(ranges);
            _self.onCopyCells.notify({ranges: ranges});

            var columns = _grid.getColumns();
            var clipText = "" ;
            for (var rg = 0; rg < ranges.length; rg++){
                var range = ranges[rg];
                for (var i=range.fromRow; i< range.toRow+1 ; i++){
                    var dt = _grid.getDataItem(i);
                    for (var j=range.fromCell; j< range.toCell+1 ; j++){
                          if (j==range.fromCell) 
                            clipText = clipText.concat(getDataItemValueForColumn(dt, columns[j]));
                          else 
                          clipText = clipText.concat("\t",getDataItemValueForColumn(dt, columns[j]));
                    }
                    clipText = clipText.concat("\r\n");
                }
            }

            var ta = _createTextBox(clipText);


            $(ta).select();
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.body.removeChild(ta);
            }, 100);

            return false;
          }
        }

        if (e.which == keyCodes.V && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) {    // CTRL + V
            var ta = _createTextBox(''); 

            setTimeout(function(){ 
                _decodeTabularData(_grid, ta);
            }, 100);

            return false;
        }
      }
    }

    function markCopySelection(ranges) {
      var columns = _grid.getColumns();
      var hash = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        for (var j = ranges[i].fromRow; j <= ranges[i].toRow; j++) {
          hash[j] = {};
          for (var k = ranges[i].fromCell; k <= ranges[i].toCell; k++) {
            hash[j][columns[k].id] = true;
          }
        }
      }
      _grid.setCellCssStyles(_copiedCellStyle, hash);
    }

    function clearCopySelection() {
      _grid.removeCellCssStyles(_copiedCellStyle);
    }

    $.extend(this, {
      "init": init,
      "destroy": destroy,
      "clearCopySelection": clearCopySelection,

      "onCopyCells": new Slick.Event(),
      "onCopyCancelled": new Slick.Event(),
      "onPasteCells": new Slick.Event()
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don Li, thank you! Your code helped me, but I've found that function handleKeyDown was faster with labs.nereo.fr version.

```
(function ($) {
    // register namespace$.extend(true, window, {
        "Slick": {
          "CellExternalCopyManager": CellExternalCopyManager
        }
    });


function CellExternalCopyManager(options) {
/*
  This manager enables users to copy/paste data from/to an external Spreadsheet application
  such as MS-Excel® or OpenOffice-Spreadsheet.

  Since it is not possible to access directly the clipboard in javascript, the plugin uses
  a trick to do it's job. After detecting the keystroke, we dynamically create a textarea
  where the browser copies/pastes the serialized data. 

  options:
    copiedCellStyle : sets the css className used for copied cells. default : "copy-manager"
    dataItemColumnValueExtractor : option to specify a custom column value extractor function

*/
var _grid;
var _self = this;
var _copiedRanges;
var _options = options || {};
var _copiedCellStyle = _options.copiedCellStyle || "copied";
var _clearCopyTI = 0;


var keyCodes = {
  'C':67,
  'V':86
}

function init(grid) {
  _grid = grid;
  _grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(handleKeyDown);      
}

function destroy() {
  _grid.onKeyDown.unsubscribe(handleKeyDown);
}

function getDataItemValueForColumn(item, columnDef) {
  if (_options.dataItemColumnValueExtractor) {
    return _options.dataItemColumnValueExtractor(item, columnDef);
  }
  return item[columnDef.field];
}

function setDataItemValueForColumn(item, columnDef, value) {
  if (_options.dataItemColumnValueSetter) {
    return _options.dataItemColumnValueSetter(item, columnDef, value);
  }
  return item[columnDef.field] = value;
}


function _createTextBox(innerText){
  var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
  ta.style.position = 'absolute';
  ta.style.left = '-1000px';
  ta.style.top = '-1000px';
  ta.value = innerText;
  document.body.appendChild(ta);
  document.designMode = 'off';
  /* Изменяем фокус на select. Сделали это, чтобы после каждого копирования скорость таблицы не уменьшалась (см. ниже). 
  ta.focus();
  */
  ta.select()
  return ta;
}
function _decodeTabularData(_grid, ta){
  var columns = _grid.getColumns();
  var clipText = ta.value;
  var clipRows = clipText.split("\r\n"); 
 var clippeds = [];

  document.body.removeChild(ta);

  for (var i=0; i<clipRows.length; i++) {
    if (clipRows[i]!="") // get rid of the last ""
      clippeds[i] = clipRows[i].split(String.fromCharCode(9)); //  "\t" 
  }

  var selectedCell = _grid.getActiveCell();
  /* Переменную activeRow зануляем (что за переменные pageSize и PageNum - непонятно)
  var activeRow = selectedCell.row + pageSize*pageNum;// getActiveCell.row starts from 0  for each page.
  */
  var activeRow = null;
  var activeCell = selectedCell.cell;
  var desty = activeRow;
  var destx = activeCell;
  var changedIds = []; // Устанавливаем переменную changedIds
  var data = _grid.getData().getItems();  

  for (var y = 0; y < clippeds.length; y++){
    for (var x = 0; x < clippeds[y].length; x++){
        var desty = activeRow + y;
      var destx = activeCell + x;
        if (desty < data.length && destx < grid.getColumns().length ) { 
            data[desty][columns[destx].field] = clippeds[y][x];
        if ( data[desty].hasOwnProperty('id')) 
          changedIds.push(data[desty].id);// record changed id used by saving function
      }
    }
  }

  _grid.invalidate();
}

function handleKeyDown(e, args) {
  var ranges;
  if (!_grid.getEditorLock().isActive() || _grid.getOptions().autoEdit) {
    if (e.which == keyCodes.ESC) {
      if (_copiedRanges) {
        e.preventDefault();
        clearCopySelection();
        _self.onCopyCancelled.notify({ranges: _copiedRanges});
        _copiedRanges = null;
      }
    }

    if (e.which == keyCodes.C && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) {    // CTRL + C
      ranges = _grid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedRanges();
  if (ranges.length != 0) {
        _copiedRanges = ranges;
        markCopySelection(ranges);
        _self.onCopyCells.notify({ranges: ranges});

        var columns = _grid.getColumns();
        var clipText = "";
    for (var rg = 0; rg < ranges.length; rg++){
            var range = ranges[rg];

    var clipTextRows = [];
    if (clipText == "" && _options.includeHeaderWhenCopying) {
        var clipTextHeaders = [];
        for (var j = range.fromCell; j < range.toCell + 1 ; j++) {
            if (columns[j].name.length > 0)
                clipTextHeaders.push(columns[j].name);
        }
        clipTextRows.push(clipTextHeaders.join("\t"));
    }

            for (var i=range.fromRow; i< range.toRow+1 ; i++){
                var clipTextCells = [];
                var dt = _grid.getDataItem(i);

                for (var j=range.fromCell; j< range.toCell+1 ; j++){
                    clipTextCells.push(getDataItemValueForColumn(dt, columns[j]));
                }
                clipTextRows.push(clipTextCells.join("\t"));
            }
            clipText += clipTextRows.join("\r\n") + "\r\n";
        }
        var ta = _createTextBox(clipText);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}


function markCopySelection(ranges) {
  var columns = _grid.getColumns();
  var hash = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    for (var j = ranges[i].fromRow; j <= ranges[i].toRow; j++) {
      hash[j] = {};
      for (var k = ranges[i].fromCell; k <= ranges[i].toCell; k++) {
        // hash[j][columns[k].id] = true;
    // Применяем стиль для скопированных ячеек
    hash[j][columns[k].id] = _copiedCellStyle;
      }
    }
  }
  _grid.setCellCssStyles(_copiedCellStyle, hash);
  clearTimeout(_clearCopyTI);
  _clearCopyTI = setTimeout(function(){
    _self.clearCopySelection();
  }, 400);
}

function clearCopySelection() {
  _grid.removeCellCssStyles(_copiedCellStyle);
}

$.extend(this, {
  "init": init,
  "destroy": destroy,
  "clearCopySelection": clearCopySelection,

  "onCopyCells": new Slick.Event(),
  "onCopyCancelled": new Slick.Event(),
  "onPasteCells": new Slick.Event()
});
}
})(jQuery);
```